# Apache Timeout on Virtual Private Server

Tags: php, apache

I'm experimenting with a virtual private server hosted on a DigitalOcean droplet. I'm on their smallest plan with 512mb memory/20GB HDD.

I've installed the Lampp Stack, PhpMyAdmin and Proftpd.

I was able to upload a test index.php file via ftp, and connecting to the IP via a browser everything worked fine.

I then uploaded a slightly bigger PHP project which onload includes several javascript/css files, including bootstrap and jquery. All of these cannot be loaded and Chrome returns a connection timed out error.

A tail 100 on apache's error.log returns the following:

```
[Fri Mar 18 09:56:31.137614 2016] [core:notice] [pid 8595] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found
sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found
[Fri Mar 18 12:35:21.665241 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 8595] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Mar 18 12:35:26.723904 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 10189] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 18 12:35:26.723959 2016] [core:notice] [pid 10189] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Mar 18 12:42:59.770363 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 10189] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Mar 18 12:43:36.105262 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1037] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 18 12:43:36.106454 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1037] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Mar 18 13:48:31.612218 2016] [:error] [pid 1042] [client 91.196.50.33:33831] script '/var/www/html/testproxy.php' not found or unable to stat
```

With no errors returned since yesterday, and on access.log

```
==> access.log <==
87.113.229.42 - - [18/Mar/2016:19:42:56 -0400] "GET /mrsps/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3865 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
141.212.122.209 - - [18/Mar/2016:21:01:56 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 191 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 zgrab/0.x"
193.124.183.50 - - [19/Mar/2016:06:08:10 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 247 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0"
67.207.157.225 - - [19/Mar/2016:08:11:36 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 210 "-" "-"
67.207.157.225 - - [19/Mar/2016:08:11:37 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 210 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"
67.207.157.225 - - [19/Mar/2016:08:11:39 -0400] "GET /CHANGELOG.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 469 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"
67.207.157.225 - - [19/Mar/2016:08:11:39 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 210 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/601.2.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.1 Safari/601.2.7"
67.207.157.225 - - [19/Mar/2016:08:11:40 -0400] "GET /readme.html HTTP/1.1" 404 467 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/601.2.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.1 Safari/601.2.7"
87.113.229.42 - - [19/Mar/2016:09:15:18 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 247 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
87.113.229.42 - - [19/Mar/2016:09:15:21 -0400] "GET /mrsps/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3865 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
root@ubuntu-512mb-lon1-01:/var/log/apache2#
```

All js and css files are well under 1mb, usually less than 200kb, so I don't see how this is timing out... Any advice on how I could debug?

EDIT:

Added result of `free -h`

[image]

Comment: can you run a "free -h" to check how much free memory you have?

Comment: @wodka done, see the edited question

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it is not about programming (as defined in the scope in the [help]). Try [su].

Answer (score 0):

you could try to add some swap space (execute as root)

```
/bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024
/sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
/sbin/swapon /var/swap.1
```

the other way would be to reduce the memory the application uses -> for more try https://superuser.com/